# IIS UrlRewrite, redirect to subpage from frontpage/root

Tags: iis-7, url-rewrite-module

I have a CMS site which host multiple sites in the same solution.
One of the sites i need to redirect the frontpage/root, to a subpage.

So when the user enters `(www).mydomain1.com` they need to be redirected to `(www).mydomain1.com/mypage`

Obviously, this redirect should only hit when they enter the root/frontpage, and not when other pages on the site is beeing visited.

How do I do this with the URL Rewrite module in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following code in web.config file under system.webserver tag.

```
<system.webServer>    
<defaultDocument>
          <files>
            <add value="Frontpage.aspx"/>
          </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Or you can set homepage or frontpage from IIS
Go to IIS Manager -> Click on Default Document (Option on Dash Board) -> Click Add... Button present in Actions -> Enter Frontpage name -> Then Ok
It's done then.

Comment: But this will also effect the other sites in the same CMS solution (and IIS site), which it should not.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

```
(\W|^)domain1.com(\W|$)
```

as pattern and `{REQUEST_URI}` as condition input with `^$` as pattern. These are then redirected to the subpage with a 301.

So bassicly, matching all inbound request on the specific domain, and then checking if the Request Uri (everything after the hostname) is empty. If it is (it is hitting the root/frontpage) then redirect to subpage as needed.